# How to print row that contain list with specific values python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I want to print df that contains 'c' as author. This is my dataframe:

| author | title |
| --- | --- |
| ['a','b','c'] | x |
| andin | y |
| NaN | z |

and if i search 'c' as author, the output like this:

| author | title |
| --- | --- |
| ['a','b','c'] | x |

my code is like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: any(['c' in x['author']]), axis=1)
```

but the output will be like 'TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable'

Comment: Is `['a','b','c']` an actual list or a string that looks like a list?

Comment: @Timus its a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `apply` on the column `df['author']` inside `loc` after droping the `NaN` values

```
df1 = df.dropna()
print(df1.loc[df1['author'].apply(lambda x: 'andin' in x)])
```

Comment: @A.NurulIstiqamah Edited the answer